# IdentityCache in Rails 4.2 fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Rails 4.2.3, IdentityCache gem 0.2.5

I am calling ZipCodeLookup.fetch_by_id(value) and I am getting the following error:

```
undefined method `fetch_value' for #<Hash:0x007fbc6d261e08>
```

I have the following attributes in my ZipCodeLookup model

```
include IdentityCache
cache_index :zip_code, unique: true
```

I haven't seen anyone else with this issue. Does anyone know how to fix this?

fyi works in Rails 4.1.x

Answer (score 0):

the error came from not clearing the cache. so run the following command in the rails console: IdentityCache.cache.clear

Answer (score 0):

I've seen the same exception before without using `IdentityCache`. In my case, some ActiveRecord models were manually marshaled via `Marshal::dump` and saved as binary stream. Then, Ruby and Rails were upgraded.

Afterwards, calling `Marshal::load` on the marshaled copies would retrieve them and `object.class` would show the right model's name, but accessing any attribute within would throw the same exception.

I had to clear the marshaled copies and generate new ones.